# Swiper Slider Mouse Hover Pagination

Tags: swiper.js

I want to make mouse hover pagination on Swiper Slider. How can I do it?

Here is my javascript code;

```
        var subSlider = new Swiper ('.subsSlider', {
          // Optional parameters
            direction: 'vertical',
            loop: true,
            // If we need pagination
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
                return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
            }
        })
```

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

By regular/normal CSS [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) style -

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet:hover{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.swiper-pagination-bullet').hover(function() {
    $( this ).trigger( "click" );
});
```